# Add attribute to an element dynamically with Angular

Tags: angular, angular5

Is there a way to turn a string from a component member to a dynamic attribute in component HTML with Angular?

```
export class ContextualMenuComponent implements OnInit {
directive: string;

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
   this.directive = "mat-mini-fab";
}
```

And then in html something like this

```
<button [directive]>click</button>
```

but I want it to actually come out as

```
<button mat-mini-fab>click</button>
```

Comment: you want to add an attribute or a directive?

Comment: As per the previous comment, it would depend on what you're really want to do. From your sample code, it seems there's some omission in the question.

Comment: Directive. mat-mini-fab is a angular material directive as far as I understand

Comment: I managed to do this, I'm about to post the answer. I'm just facing another small issue, but I'm almost there.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an HTML attribute, what's needed is to add a component dynamically, because the exact type isn't known at build time. Because Angular doesn't know which components will be needed (because they're not known statically), they need to be added in `entryComponents` in an NgModule. You'll use `ComponentFactoryResolver` for this.

Below, `AdItem` is a component type to be injected. They're not injected by selector, but by class.

```js
export class AdBannerComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() ads: AdItem[];
  currentAddIndex: number = -1;
  @ViewChild(AdDirective) adHost: AdDirective;
  subscription: any;
  interval: any;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.loadComponent();
    this.getAds();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  loadComponent() {
    this.currentAddIndex = (this.currentAddIndex + 1) % this.ads.length;
    let adItem = this.ads[this.currentAddIndex];

    let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(adItem.component);

    let viewContainerRef = this.adHost.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();

    let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    (<AdComponent>componentRef.instance).data = adItem.data;
  }

  getAds() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.loadComponent();
    }, 3000);
  }
}
```

Source: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#loading-components

Comment: This isn't quite what I am looking as my components aren't custom, they are existing angular material button components. I just want to know is there is a way to dynamically add them to a template.

Comment: @americanslon tbh, I don't think it matters if they're custom or not. and this is the way to insert components whose type is only known at runtime.